# How can I add "not italic" to a style?

Tags: microsoft-word

I created a style for inline snippets of computer code in MS Word. When I applied the style to text in a paragraph that was italicised, I noticed that the text remained italicised, and so I selected it and "un-italicised" it. I noticed that the text now has the manual formatting option "not italic":

[image]

I would like to add this formatting rule to the code style, but can't figure out how to do it. It isn't done using the italic icon in the "Modify Style" window. Nor does the Format Font window give this option as far as I can see. The "update ... to match selection" feature seems to overwrite the preexisting attributes of the code style.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your Code style is based on a Quote style that is italic, rather than (say) a Normal style that is regular.  Remember that styles in MS Word are hierarchical, so any changes you now make to the Quote style will be inherited by your Code style.  This *may* be what you want, but it probably isn't.

The `Reveal Formatting` panel with `Distinguish source style` checked makes this a bit clearer:

[image: Reveal formatting panel]

In general, if you want some text to have your Code style then it's better to apply the style via the Ribbon/Panel rather than manually change the text properties to have the *appearance* of your Code style.  After all, one of the reasons you defined this style is to avoid micro-managing the formatting of each code instance in your document.  Also, while those bits of text may have the appearance of the style, Word won't know that they're actually supposed to be that style, so they won't be updated if the style is modified.